# Why do I get Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on writing to a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ioerror

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am running some tests and writing the results to a file. The portion of the code which writes to a file is the following (in a class called Tester):

```
 @staticmethod
 def printHeader(resultsFileName):
        if not os.path.isfile(resultsFileName):
            # The file does not exist, thus
            # we need to print the header

            # Opens the results file
            with open(resultsFileName,"a") as file:
                # Prints the header 
                file.write("A long header")


@staticmethod
def printResults(resultsFileName,otherArguments):

    # Prints the header if it does not exist
    Tester.printHeader(resultsFileName)

    # Prints the results
    with open(resultsFileName,"a") as file:

        file.write(otherArguments)
```

Sometimes I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "tester.py", line 88, in methodOne
  File "tester.py", line 441, in printResults
  File "tester.py", line 428, in printHeader
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'results.txt'
```

while other times it runs smoothly. I cannot figure out where the problem is. Any ideas?

**NOTE1**: I have `rwx`permission on the directory where the file is written.
**NOTE2**: The error happens after several lines of results have already been written. Thus, it happens when the code is checking whether the header should be printed or not (but it is not supposed to print it, since the file exists).

**UPDATE 1**:

As suggested, I have changed my code to avoid opening and closing the file multiple times. Now it writes everything in one shot. This is the updated code:

```
  @staticmethod
  def printResults(resultsFileName,otherArguments):

    # Prints the header if it does not exist                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    if not os.path.exists(resultsFileName):

        # The file does not exist, thus                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        # we need to print the header                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

        # Opens the results file               
        # HERE IS WHERE ERRNO 13 HAPPENS
        # STRANGELY, THE FILE DOES EXIST 
        # AS SEVERAL LINES OF RESULTS 
        # HAVE ALREADY BEEN WRITTEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        with open(resultsFileName,"w") as file:

            # Prints the header                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            file.write("A suitable header")
            # Prints the results                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            file.write(otherArguments)
    else:

        # Prints the results                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        with open(resultsFileName,"a") as file:
            file.write(otherArguments)
```

It seems that `os.path.exists()` at some point returns `FALSE`even if the file does exist. Probably, there is something revoking me permission to write (perhaps the file is not properly closed after writing?).

The explanation of `os.path.exists()` says that:

> On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed my code to the following, to avoid `os.path.isfile()`:

```
# Opens the results file                                                                                                                                                                            
with open(resultsFileName,"a") as file:
     if file.tell() == 0:
         # Prints the header                                                                                                                                                                         
         file.write("Header")
         # Prints the results                                                                                                                                                                        
         file.write(otherArguments)
         file.close()
      else:

         # Prints the results
         file.write(otherArguments)                                                                                                                                                                        
         file.close()
```

Nevertheless, ERRNO 13 happens at `with open(resultsFileName,"a") as file:`.
I have `rw`permissions both on the folder and on the file, on which several lines are written before the error happens. The OS is Linux.

Comment: Did you check the permission of the directory you the program is trying to write to ?

Comment: Usually this means you have the file open

Comment: When the file doesn't exist, instead of using mode 'a' to append, try using mode 'w' for write. The behavior I experience is that 'a' will create the file and properly append, but worth trying. Perhaps in on your system append fails if the file doesn't exist, but still succeeds to create it on the disk.

Comment: @hansolo I have `rwx`permissions of the directory. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @RaamEE I have changed 'a' to 'w' in the printHeader method and running some tests.

Comment: Can you paste "ls -l results.txt"? You might have accesss to directory, but not to the file, example: ebajgrz@IE-00001696:/tmp$ mkdir dir ebajgrz@IE-00001696:/tmp$ chmod 777 dir ebajgrz@IE-00001696:/tmp$ touch dir/file ebajgrz@IE-00001696:/tmp$ sudo chmod 000 dir/file ebajgrz@IE-00001696:/tmp$ echo test > dir/file bash: dir/file: Permission denied

Comment: @gbajson the result of `ls -l results.txt`is `-rw------- 1 user users 8346 Feb  5 15:10 folder/results.txt`

Comment: Have you came up with anything new?

Comment: @DanielReyhanian Yes, have a look at the edited post

Comment: I have the same problem. I think there is a delay between each run. Python closes the file and before it closes completely, it tries to open it again. (in my case it happens to me with a log of executions).

Did you find a solution other than adding a sleep?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try closing the file result.txt before running the program (I'd its open).
2. Check the writing permissions.
3. Another cause might be writing into a .txt file in a directory without those permissions. Try running python from the specified directory.

Comment: The error happens also if I add a `file.close()` after `file.write()`. I have checked the permissions of the folder and of the file, and I have writing permission in the folder and on the file.

Comment: @ZzKr Try running the interpreter / IDE as Administrator?

Comment: @ZzKr Another suggestions is to check your path. Maybe it's wrong? Maybe it's not the full one? (try including the ones that seem pretty obvious, for example C:\Windows).

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.isfile(path)` returns True if `path` exists AND is a file AND you have (at least) read permissions on it. IOW, it returns False if `path` exists but is a directory and/or you don't have permissions on it. So your test is wrong from the start - `os.path.exists()` would be a better choice.  But anyway: those operations are not atomic so the file could well be created between the moment where you test for it's existence and the moment where you try to open it, so the whole design is actually unsafe. Also, stating, opening and closing a file are all costly operations, so I suggest - if possible - that you rethink your whole design to open a file only once and only close it once when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file is open with another program. If so, you can try closing them all.

Cheers!
Surely it will work